# How to echo or return value based on ajax or internal call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a class named `ProductDetails`. I have a bunch of methods in this class that should either return a value (if the method is called inside the class) or should echo it, if the method is called as a result of an ajax call.

My ajax handler is a file named `gateway.php`. In it I do the following:

```
$p = new ProductDetails($productId);
$p->getRecentProductFeedback();
```

Now in the `ProductDetails` class, `getRecentProductFeedback()` generates an array of feedback data. What I do with it is the following:

```
public function getRecentProductFeedback()
{
    //...code to get recent feedback as array
    $this->echoReturn($feedbackArray);
}
```

The `echoReturn()` function is meant to handle if the result should be echoed or returned (based on whether the call is AJAX or not)

```
public function echoReturn($data)
{
        if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) 
        && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest')
        {
            if(is_array($data))
            {
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            else
            {
                echo $data;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return $data;
        }
    }
```

This was working fine. Now my problem is that inside my class I have another method, `getSimilarProducts()` (which is also called by my gateway) that needs to call `getRecentProductFeedback()`.

So my `gateway.php` for this ajax call is:

```
$p = new ProductDetails($productId);
$p->getSimilarProducts();
```

And in ProductDetails class:

```
public function getSimilarProducts()
{
    //...code to get similar product and then..
    $this->getRecentProductFeedback();
}
```

The problem is that in above call to getRecentProductFeedback, the `echoReturn()` ALWAYS echoes the data but I want it to be returned..

How do I handle this with minimum disruption to the code? :(

because I have a LOT of functions that do `echoReturn` in the end... ideally I would like it that the function can be tweaked so that if the echoReturn call was made from within the class it always returns else it echoes.

Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems complicated, I would have separated this and made functions and files that are called by ajax only, but in your case why not just pass a boolean argument to the functions that tells them what to do.

Comment: I guess, in the end that is what I will need to do.Its just that there are so many functions that will need to be modified to include this new parameter...this is a legacy class that was handed down to me.. :( I was just hoping someone might have a neater trick I am no aware of which might solve this...

Comment: probably best to just have two versions of the call, and the "echo" version can be a simple wrapper around the "return" version. basically kind of like wordpress does: `somefunc()` outputs the data, `get_somefunc()` RETURNS the data.